# In-app purchase for core data sync?

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store, in-app-purchase, synchronization

I any to offer core data sync for my app, but it is going to be a major time investment and I want to make sure that it pays off financially. Is it possible to have data sync be a for-pay feature in the App Store? I thought it might not be possible, because apple offers iCloud for free. But especially if the data sync is being done by a third party server and not iCloud (which has its own issues), is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [In-app purchase](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html) results in a unique id, which can serve as a [receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html). You use that id to determine whether the feature is available. Be sure to validate at your server so that jail-breakers don't get your stuff for free.

---

***Update:***
Ok, now I understand what you're asking.

Whether Apple will allow iCloud syncing to be considered additional functionality according to the [in-app purchase guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf) (pdf) is an interesting question. Yes iCloud is offered for free, but there are paid plans as well. My experience here is limited to the model that I adopted of two app versions - paid and free. My paid apps sync data with each other, the free versions don't even link my sync code. I wouldn't try it via in-app purchase.

That being said, if you decide to use your own data sync service, then the sky is the limit, and you won't have any problems regarding rejection. You are free to offer any additional functionality you wish. Just think DropBox. I think your bigger decision here is whether to make the storage a non-consumable or a subscription.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question -- I know that I can set up in-app purchase. But the question is, can I charge an in-app purchase for iCloud sync?

Comment: Read the links I provided. After you learn about in-app purchase, you will learn how to track whether a purchase has been made at all (using receipts). Once you know how to do that, you will be able to control iCloud sync. No, there is no Apple-provided call [iCloudThingy doSyncIfPurchaseHasBeenMadeByUserOfThisApp].

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't answer the question. I already have in-app purchase in my app and know how to make it work. The question is, will Apple allow you to charge for core data sync? Or will they say that you need to make it available for free because iCloud is something they are pushing as a selling feature of the iOS ecosystem?

Comment: Oh! Now you have changed the question. I don't know the answer, but I will review the contract and get back to you. My first guess is that you will be able to charge for it, if not via in-app purchase, then you could certainly release a paid version which includes iCloud sync - indeed this is the way I have approached the problem in the past.

Comment: Yeah, most people would create two apps. One that syncs, one that doesn't. That is how I would do it. In-app purchases can get a little sticky.